# Gitlab-ce css and js not found with ssl

Tags: ssl, gitlab, apache2

I have installed Gitlab-ce on Rapsberry Pi 4 (4gb) and I run it with Apache2.

When I run it with http, like with address http://git.home.lan/gitlab, it works just fine.
When I try to use https though, it loads the gitlab and even the projects, but it cannot find the css or the js in the /assets/ path.

Some files, like https://git.home.lan/gitlab/assets/highlight/themes/white-3144068cf4f603d290f553b653926358ddcd02493b9728f62417682657fc58c0.css fail with 404 not found.

When I try to manually enter the css path with the browser though, I get a blank page, but the browser console says

```
The character encoding of the plain text document was not declared. 
The document will render with garbled text in some browser configurations if the document contains characters from outside the US-ASCII range. 
The character encoding of the file needs to be declared in the transfer protocol or file needs to use a byte order mark as an encoding signature.
```

When I enter the css path with http, it loads normally.

The configuration in apache2 sites-available conf is as follows:

```
ProxyPass         /gitlab http://127.0.0.1:9099/gitlab
ProxyPassReverse  /gitlab http://127.0.0.1:9099/gitlab
RequestHeader     add X-Forwarded-Proto https
```

The gitlab.rb has the following content:

```
external_url 'https://git.home.lan/gitlab'

web_server['username'] = 'apache' #'gitlab-www'
web_server['group'] = 'apache' #'gitlab-www'

nginx['enable'] = false

unicorn['listen'] = '127.0.0.1'
unicorn['port'] = 9099

 git_data_dirs({
   "default" => {
     "path" => "/mnt/[path_omitted]/git-data"
    }
 })
```

The working http setup is really the same with https replaced with http.

I have found some related issues, but nothing exactly identical, and thus the solutions have not worked either.

Ps. I have really no idea if this is a stackoverflow or raspberrypi.stackexchange or superuser case or even a gitlab issue, because I do not fully understand the cause. I chose stackoverflow based on the other questions posed here, but if you think this was the wrong forum, please be civil about it and I will move it.